# Spring boot unable to read from profile specific yaml file

Tags: java, spring-boot

I was playing around with spring boot and attempted to create a profile specific configuration file. I called it `application-local.yml`.

And added:

```
spring:
 profiles:
  active: local

 mysql:
  db:
   url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?serverTimezone=UTC
   driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   username: root
   password:

hibernate:
 dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
 show_sql: false

server:
 port: 8080
```

And in my DatabaseConfig.java file I attempt to read from `application-local.yml` and configure the database:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Value("${spring.mysql.db.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${spring.mysql.db.username}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${spring.mysql.db.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${spring.mysql.db.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;

    //hibernate
    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String hibernateDialect;

    @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
    private String hibernateShowSql;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSource.setUsername(userName);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean =
                new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("xxxx");

        JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", hibernateShowSql);
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Now I get the error it's unable to

> Error creating bean with name 'databaseConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.mysql.db.url' in value "${spring.mysql.db.url}"

but when I rename my property file to `application.yml`. It works perfectly fine.

I also attempted to run from the terminal using gradle command: `./gradlew -Dspring.profiles.active=local bootRun` but I get the same error. It only works when I refactor the YAML file to `application.yml`. What am I doing wrong? I intend to have 3 profiles such as local, dev and prod.

Comment: If you are using spring boot, then why aren't you using the datasource auto-configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Either add the following in your gradle file

```
bootRun {
  profile: local
}
```

or try

```
./gradlew bootRun -Dspring.profiles.active=local
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by adding

```
Spring:
  profiles: local
```

Please make sure its indented properly.